# Change password or add user in LDAP with PHP

Tags: php, ldap, openldap, password-encryption, change-password

Since a recent update in my LDAP server (using Directory Server v2.1-2428 on a Synology NAS running DSM 6, latest subversion) I cannot change a password (or a new user containing a password) using PHP.

Before the update, I used PHP ldap_add or ldap_mod with the userPassword attribute. However, now I get the error message `Warning: ldap_add(): Add: Constraint violation` when trying to create a new userPassword.

When creating a new user via the admin GUI on the NAS, I can look up the userPassword entry, which appears in the database as follows (slightly modified for privacy):    `{crypt}$6$e49q9SvU$.pSl1C8Ew6WTu24yipUI8kjx7qv2GxWhKAUOBmuAVeRmJ1JV/WvWriVYZJeDDtBxekeepatdaKl0ulQdjsmCP.`

This means the database accepts SSHA-512 password entries right?

Thing I've tried to add a new password:

1. Adding exactly the same password hash as displayed above as userPassword
   --> Constraint violation error
2. Trying to look up the password algorithm in the NAS' source code. This revealed the following line: `rootpw {CRYPT}$1$CL$0fRYicA9KsmHaiV1SRj5q/`.
   Simply using this as new password doesn't work either.
3. Look up a different PHP function, like an equivalent to Linux command ldappasswd, but this doesn't seem to exist for PHP.

Of course I'd prefer to use a proper hashing/encryption mechanism like SSHA-512, but I'm not sure what is and what isn't supported by Directory Server.

**I really hope someone can bring me a step further! If I should further clarify things, please let me know.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the solution was to ask Synology over and over te help finding a solution. They changed the password policy back to version before the update to v2.1-2428, now it works again.

If there would be another solution available which is compatible with recent versions of OpenLDAP, sharing would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Constraint Violation when trying to change a password seems like a Directory Server Password Policy enforcement.
The Directory Server logs should contain more details about the error, but it is possible that the policy has been set to reject passwords that have already been used (like the last 3 passwords). A Directory Server password policy may enforce many checks and constraints on passwords : length, no reuse, variations in characters sets, no plain words...
You might need to check through the Synology directory server documentation or release notes to have the details of the default password policy.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In Directory Server's advanced settings, there are various options to set password policy. However, I've got none of them activated, so there's no restriction on the password choice.

The log (/var/log/slapd.log) reveals:
`Jun 10 21:12:33 IFMSA-NL slapd[29121]: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Jun 10 21:13:05 IFMSA-NL slapd[10237]: [main.c:736] @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.40 (May 25 2016 17:16:08) $
    root@build1:/source/openldap-2.4.x/servers/slapd`
However, there is no log entry from the moment I try to add the userPassword, no idea why

Comment: Well, looking at Synology DSM 6.0 notes, Password strength rules has been added and enabled for users. https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DirectoryServer/ldap_user.
I don't have this enabled on my NAS, and I don't work with OpenLDAP either... But it seems that there is an option on DSM to get better diagnostic on login failure. You might want to try that.

Comment: Yeah, but as I said I haven't got any of the rules activated, so apart from the possibility that Synology changed something under the hood, this doesn't lead to something I can change to make it work, do you think? Do you mean the option "Show more information when login fails"? This means that you get an error message when loggin in on DSM. That's not the problem I'm talking about: I want to add the userPassword attribute, and I get the Constraint violation error in PHP.

Comment: I was thinking that the option might also help (as it's possible that it implies giving LDAP password policy details).